# Theme Drupal comment reply page exactly like comment submitted page

Tags: theming, nodes

I have created a custom content type 'article' where a custom comment field has been added along with other fields like images, taxonomy terms, etc. In the theme file (page.html.twig) for this content type 'article', I have retrieved a few field values(not all) from the node object using PHP/twig code like node.getCreatedTime/node.field_article_tag, page.content and a view for a related node content. This works fine and the article page is displaying content fields, and page content/related views with comments.

However, when I submit a blank comment the reply page does not contain the node fields along with a view that utilizes node term reference for the related content.  This is reasonable since the comment reply page does not belong to a node entity.

My question is how can I access the node ID in the template file for the reply page so that, I can access the fields associated with the submitted article page to theme the page(reply) exactly like the article page(page.html.twig)?

Thanks